# Python で、負の数を使った剰余算について

Tags: python

Pythonコード

```
print(-7 % 2)  # 1
print(-7 % 3)  # 2
print(7 % -2)  # -1
print(-7 % 3)  # 2
print(7 % -3)  # -2
```

となるのですが、理由が分かりません？

Answer (score 1):

まず演算子の結合順序について、Python では `%` より単項のマイナス `-` の方が[優先度が高い](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)ので、たとえば `-7 % 2` は `(-7) % 2` と解釈されます。`-(7 % 2)` ではないです。

そして Python の余り演算子 `%` はふたつ目の引数と[同じ符号の余りを返します](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)。このため `(-7) % 2` は `1` を返しますが、`7 % (-2)` は `-1` を返します。

この「結合の優先順序」「負の数が絡んだ場合の余り」はプログラミング言語によって[仕様が異なる](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%89%B0%E4%BD%99%E6%BC%94%E7%AE%97)ため、まずはドキュメントを確認してみてください。

---

※補足：`-7 % 3` が `2` になる理由

これは Python 以前に数学の話ですが、-7 = 3 * (-3) + 2 と書くと余りは 2 になります。
また -7 = 3 * (-2) - 1 と捉えて余りを -1 とすることもでき、ここに選択の余地があります。
同様に `7 % -3` や `-7 % -3` も統一的に扱えるようにするやり方がいくつかあり、言語によってやり方が異なっています。

Comment: 大体わかりました。数学的には、 7 = -2 * (-4) -1   ですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

理由は「そういう仕様に決めたから」です。仕様：整数の除算は負の無限大方向への丸めとする。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html の (2)

また `(x//y)*y + (x%y) = x` にならないと不都合が生じるので剰余のほうも必然的に決まります。

この挙動は他の言語たとえば [c](/questions/tagged/c) や [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) とは異なりますし、一般的な日本人が中学校で教わる負の数の乗除算とも異なりますが、そもそも負の数の除算は自分の都合の良いように定義してよい [除法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%99%A4%E6%B3%95) ので [python](/questions/tagged/python) ではこう決めたってことで了承してください。

# なぜそう決めたのかの rationale はオイラも知りたい。

Comment: 最新の指導要領しか確認していませんが、負の数が絡んでくるような剰余は義務教育の範疇では無いような気がします（分数にしそうです）。また、日本での教育のされ方と Python の決まり方には関連が無さそうです。　／　[この Wikipedia のページ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%89%B0%E4%BD%99%E6%BC%94%E7%AE%97)に言語ごとの一覧表があるのですが、一部の Pascal のように常に正を返す場合や、Ada のようにひとつ目・ふたつ目の引数に符号を合わせる関数を別々に用意している場合などあり、C/C++ でよくある挙動が昔から一般的だったと言っていいかどうかには疑問が残るかなあ、と思っています。

Comment: オイラのときは（ウン十年前）１．異符号の商は負数、同符号の商は正数・２．そうすると必然的に剰余の符号は決まる・したがって商は０方向への丸め、剰余は被除数と同符号になると教わりましたが、今の指導要綱でどうかは知らないっす。除法を好きに定義してよいと教わるのは大学生。プログラム好きは中高生の頃に各種言語の仕様を調べて愕然とするってことでしょうか。